# Version control approach for inconsistent changes

Tags: git, github, version-control

Let assume I have github repo with a project that already has lots of followers.

Now I want to make totally inconsistent changes into implementation with saving the same general concept.

What are my exact steps in terms of version control?

- Should I create other repository for new major version? (Like Zend did for Zend Framework 2)
- Or should I just create tag with current version and use the same repo mentioning in README file that people are able to download also previous version?
- Or should I create separate branch for it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the changes are really inconcistent (new API, new features, ...), it is then considered [as a Fork](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_%28software_development%29), in its original meaning ("independent development on it, creating a distinct piece of software")

In that case, creating a new repo is best, and allows you to develop an independent set of branches for managing that new version.
The alternative is mixing those new branches with the "legacy" branches, which can become messy to manage.

Comment: Yup. It seems likely people are going to wind up interested in only one version or another, and even though refspecs and a recognizable pattern in branch names make it easy to configure downstreams to follow just the one or the other version's development in a single repo, why make them learn how to use refspecs for that when they already know how to use clone?  refspecs also make it easy to combine histories from multiple repos for anybody that wants to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can open a new branch. Your followers had access to the old and new code. But i'm not sure if this is an "official" way of doing it right. But it worked for me in the past.